# Contour integral and Gamma function

Tags: complex-analysis

So I am trying to prove one of the relations involving the Gamma function, namely that $\Gamma (z) \Gamma (1-z) = \frac{\pi}{\sin{\pi z}} $

Got to the step when I need to compute the following integral using contour integration:

$I= \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{-z}}{1+x} dx $

Not sure how to get started, mainly because I am confused by the nature residues of the integrand. I know there should be a residue at x=-1, now what about the residue at x=0 for which the numerator would blow up. Would they be of order z? Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Make the change of variables $x=e^{y}$ and consider the counterclockwise-oriented closed contour of integration in the $y$-plane which consists of the line $\mathbb{R}$, $2\pi i +\mathbb{R}$ and two vertical segments of length $2\pi$ at $\pm \infty$.

Comment: mhh, so I get $\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^y e^{-y z}}{1+e^y} dy$ correct? Now why this contour in particular, and would my y be zero along the real line? Confused as to how to do this

Comment: The contributions of vertical segments vanish, the contribution of the line $\mathbb{R}$ is equal to the integral you are actually interested in, and the contribution of the line $\mathbb{R}+2\pi i$ will give again the same integral but with a prefactor of the form $e^{-2\pi i z}$. On the other hand the contour is closed and you can compute it by residues (the only pole inside is $y=i\pi$). Hence you will get a relation of type $(1-e^{-2\pi i z}) I=\mathrm{smth} $. That factor $1-e^{-2\pi i z}$ will produce you the sine in the denominator of the reflexion relation for the Gamma function

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks.